# Odoo 10 : Security groups are not working on edit/create button

Tags: python, xml, security, menu, odoo

**Aim** : to  make appear the Edit/create button only for user group : **Manager**

**Module name** : Simcard

**Model Name** : simcard_simcard

my csv file :

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
demo_admin, Model admin access,model_simcard_simcard,simcard.group_manager,1,1,1,1
demo_user, Model user access,model_simcard_simcard,simcard.group_user,0,0,0,0
```

My user_groups.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>
    <record model="ir.module.category" id="module_management">
      <field name="name">Simcard</field>
      <field name="description">User access level for this module</field>
      <field name="sequence">3</field>
    </record>

   <record id="group_user" model="res.groups">
     <field name="name">User</field>
     <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
     <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
     <field name="category_id" ref="simcard.module_management"/>
    </record>

    <record id="group_manager" model="res.groups">
      <field name="name">Manager</field>
      <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('simcard.group_user'))]"/>
      <field name="category_id" ref="simcard.module_management"/>
    </record>
</data>
</odoo>
```

My views.xml :

```
<record id="remove_edit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">remove.edit</field>
    <field name="model">simcard.simcard</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="simcard.view_sim_form"/>
    <!-- <field name="groups_id" eval="[(4, [ref('simcard.group_manager')])]"/> -->
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//form" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="edit">true</attribute>
            <attribute name="groups">simcard.group_manager</attribute>

        </xpath>
    </field>
    </record>
```

This Edit button still appears for normal users.

Answer (score 0):

In the csv, in model_id:id column, add your **module_name.** before:

```
simcard.model_simcard_simcard
```

Comment: Done but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You better solve this by using 2 records of `ir.rule`, one global(will apply for all the users and groups, without specifying a group) to restrict the create and write actions with a domain_force like:

```
[(1,'=',1)]
```

And another record associated with the group `simcard.group_manager` to allow the create and edit actions with the same domain_force:

```
[(1,'=',1)]
```

And remove all of those view customizations